# Matplotlib, corrupted graphical representation error

Tags: python, debugging, matplotlib, error-handling, matplotlib-basemap

I have been developing a GUI using `PyQt4` and within this GUI I implement a graph (via MatPlotLib. However, when I initially run the interface I get an error message that says something along the lines of : (Note: This still compiles and runs, it just messes up the visual element of the graph)

```
 list index out of range
 tick = self.majorTicks[i] #This line is from MatPlotLib's axis.py
```

Any idea what could generate this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is enough information in the question to be completely sure, but I think the list `self.majorTicks` does not have an element corresponding to the index `i` which is why you get an `IndexError` (I am guessing this is the error that Python has thrown).

Comment: Sorry for the limited information, yes that is the error python is throwing. however, when I manipulate their axis.py file, it still causes the graph animation to build incorrectly.